# C - malloc bidimensional array when one size is known

Tags: c

How can I malloc an array of n elements each of whom I know is an array of two chars?

I tried something like this but the compilers says it's invalid:

```
char *candidates_top[2] = malloc(sizeof(char[2]) * n);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
char (*candidates_top)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*candidates_top)*n);
```

You need to read the type of the new variable `candidates_top` from the inside out: `candidates_top` is a pointer `(*...)` to an array of two elements `[2]` which happen to be of type `char`. It's like you would create an array of `n` integers with

```
int *intArray = malloc(sizeof(*intArray)*n);
```

with the only difference that in the case of `candidates_top` the array elements are themselves arrays.

Indexing is just as you would expect:

```
candidates_top[7][0] = '4';
candidates_top[7][1] = '2';
```

Comment: This works. Can you explain a little better, please?

Comment: @pistacchio Yes, I was just writing the explanation as you were writing your comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
char *candidates_top[2];
```

declares `candidates_top` to be an array of two pointers to `char`. You seem to want `candidates_top` to be a pointer to an array of two `char` which you get with

```
char (*candidates_top)[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this makes your ears bleed:

```
char (*candidates_top)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*candidates_top)*n);
```

you can clean it up with a `typedef`:

```
typedef char twos[2];
//....
twos *candidates_top=malloc(sizeof(twos)*n);
```